# When using psutil to measure the CPU and RAM usage of a python script, where do I call it in the file?

Tags: python, memory-management, python-3.7

So say I have the following python script:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
        print(number)
```

Would I call psutil.virtual_memory() and psutil.cpu_percent() at the end of the file or at the start if I wanted to measure the memory usage of this particular file? For example:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
        print(number)
cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()
```

I can't find anywhere where they show an example of performing it like this

Answer (score 1):

So if the python file is executed, the entire file contents will be added to a buffer, this will be the base overhead used. Other things like runtime reading a file could affect this, but since you aren't doing that:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
        print(number)
```

Adding

```
cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
        print(number)
```

Would show you all cpu/memory usage before the Numbers list is loaded into memory, different from the python file buffer, there would be a memory allocation added there for `Numbers`

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
        print(number)
cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()
```

Added after would still show Numbers in memory, since nothing has unallocated it, the pointer is still there, although you may be able to view the slight spike from parsing through Numbers, and a new memory reference of `number` would associate to the last entry in the list, since the for loop doesn't auto clear the pointer, it just allocates each entry of `Numbers` to the loop variable.

For the best readings, any large scale processing could be added to a background Process of Thread, and reading system memory/cpu use would still accommodate for those usages.